# How can I make MinGW gcc ignore the InternalName from the VERSIONINFO when linking against DLLs?

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

I just compiled Harfbuzz from source on Windows. It downloaded and compiled all the dependencies resulted in DLLs with Linux-like filenames such as `libfreetype-6.dll` The problem is if I link this library against my application a dependency to `freetype.dll` is added instead. So in order to make my application I need to keep libfreetype-6.dll for Harfbuzz and a copy named as freetype.dll to make my application work.

It looks like MinGW treats the InternalName property in VERSIONINFO as SONAME and adds the dependecy to that name instead of the library's filename. Is there a way to override this behavior and add the dependency to libfreetype-6.dll instead?

I have tried to edit the InternalName property in CFF Explorer but it doesn't let me do that.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing the binary DLL file with extension `.dll` with the import library with prefix `lib` and extenstion `.dll.a`? You should indeed link with the `lib<name>.dll.a` file which will indeed add the `<name>.dll` dependancy.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I don't think I have the import library, just the dll. But if linking against the dll.a works then I'll look for finding a way to get dll.a file for the dll.